# Alphabet letter with Uppercase and Lowercase

Tags: java

Hello Sir/Ma'am i need help i would to like output the Alphabet letter like this using loop(any loop ) in Java Im Beginner =(.

Aa Bb Cc Dd Ee Ff Gg Hh Ii Jj Kk Ll Mm Nn Oo Pp Qq Rr Ss Tt Uu Vv Ww Xx Yy Zz

Comment: You should first show what You have tried and why You failed. What problems You faced. This is not a code writing service. Suggestion: use loop and ASCII table.

Comment: Did you try to write any code? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: 4 lines and its working. id recommend a for loop, controlled with a char

Comment: https://code.sololearn.com/#java this is my code i search many times in google and stackoverflow to answer my question,However its is never been answered.I make a/an account  here (newly acc).My brain is hurting now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int A = 65;
    int a = 97;

    for (int i = 0; i< 26; i++) {
        System.out.print((char)(A+i)+""+ (char)(a+i) + "\t");
    }
}
```

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are many options.

You can create this kind of sets with guava's Range or just iterate throught chars (ASCII numbers may be helpfut too).

Comment: this is my code 


import java.util.*;
class Alphabet{
public static void main (String args[]){

for(char a = 'A'; a <= 'Z'; a++){
for(char b = 'a' ; b <='z' ; b++)
System.out.print(a + " " + b);
}
}
}

Comment: Remember about variables naming. "a" and "b" is not a good name for variable.